# Xamarin IOS : firebase add document with custom ID

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

How to add document with custom ID in firebase for IOS, I found only one method "AddDocument" but there is no argument to specify the custom id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is called [setting a document](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/main/docs/Firebase/CloudFirestore/GettingStarted.md#set-a-document) in the documentation. From there:

```
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
db.GetCollection ("cities").GetDocument ("LA").SetData (docData, HandleDocumentActionCompletion);
```

The above works no matter if the `LA` document already exists or not, the `GetDocument ("LA")` merely sets up a reference to the document location - similar to how `AddDocument` generates a new, unique document location.